# Is there anyway I can grab onto an inner div to style that i don't have direct access to

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I am using an npm package in my ReactJS application.

In the package I have access to a custom style prop that i can add a style object to change accordingly.

The problem im having is that the Package itself is composed of the following:

```
<div><span>CONTENT</span></div>
```

While this is what I have access to

```
<Package customStyle={{}} />
```

As it has no className just a plain div with an inner span tag, how can i style the inner span tag as that is what is causing my styling issue?

Comment: You need to add some more details, including an example of the component rendered in context, and the component code itself.  Otherwise it's going to be hard for anyone to answer this question well.

Comment: @MattMorgan the package renders out a parent div with a child span. When passing in the customStyle prop it injects inline style to the parent div. The issue im facing is that it's styling on the child span tag thats causing my issue. I'm wondering is there anyway i can pass in an object that will allow me to style the child span - i have tried const span = { "&:first-child" : background: red } for example

Comment: Use a css selector that targets the inner `<span>`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not ideal but you could work around react and do something like wrapping the component with your own div that you can add an id to and then simply adding a class to its grandchild.

```
let span = document.querySelector('#idOfYourDiv').children[0].children[0];
span.classList.add('myClass')
```

now you have a class on that span that you can style.

Answer (score 0):

The other possible option could be like this

1. wrap the external `Package` component
2. use `>` known as child combinator to select the child `span` from the class `.wrapper`
   *Consider using your browser's DevTools to inspect elements and identify more precise selectors for targeting the child span.

your jsx/tsx

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <Package customStyle={{}} />
</div>
```

your css

```
.wrapper > div > span{
  // style the child span
}
```